# communication between asp.net and silverlight two different applications

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-5.0

I m new to web development

I have two different applications

1. asp.net license system
2. silverlight application

on asp.net button click I want to openup silverlight on next tab & i want to pass userid & password variable

silverlight should access those variables at loadtime & according to the user it will disable few tools in silverlight application

I dont want to use queryString

i tried with http POST, webRequest with no luck

How can I pass userid & password to the silverlight?

Thanks & Regards
usr22

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InitParams of the Silverlight object.

When you generate the page containing the Silverlight application, you can pass informations to the Silverlight application using the 'InitParams' parameter. Beware that if your data is sensitive (passwords, DRM, etc...) you should at least obfuscate them because they'll be in the page source.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)